# Pycharm Shell script and Python

Tags: python, django, pycharm

In Pycharm configuration, I want to execute a shell command before running Python script

I used the `Before launch` section but the problem is it executes the shell in another terminal which makes the python script doesn't see the configs I set in the shell file

Is there a way to solve that without need to write a Python file that runs both inside same terminal?

Note: I can't edit the main python file, it's manage.py from Django app

Comment: call `os.system(cmd)` at the beggining of a script?

Comment: I can't edit the python script, it's manage.py from Django